# Efficient Javascript Module pattern with private/public methods

Tags: javascript, performance, module, closures

I am exploring ways of writing Javascript modules with performance in mind.

```
//My lib
var MyModule = function(callback){
    var count = 0;

    main();    //ugly in my opinion

    //Function I want to be public.
    function main(){
        count ++;
        window.specialApi.doWorkAndCallback(secret);
        //…
    }

    //Function I want to keep private
    //It needs to access to counter variable (#closure)
    function secret(){
        if(count === 2){
            callback();
        } 
    }

    //private function 
    //other private function
    //…
};


//Later anyone else can use MyModule.
MyModule(function(){console.log("ok");});
```

The problem I spot here is that each time I call MyModule(), the JS VM will reinterpret the whole function list which is not good for performance.

Is there a pattern that allows me to do the following:

- Expose the **main** function.
- Keep the **secret** function private. Note the counter variable that may harden the task.
- Parse only once **MyModule**

Thanks

Comment: "the JS VM will reinterpret the whole function list" - how do you know?

Comment: This is my own understanding I didn't measure it in anyway. So may be I am wrong.

Comment: Modern JavaScript runtime systems handle code in very sophisticated ways. Generally it's pointless to worry about such things unless and until you encounter a genuine performance issue. Then it's time to break out a code profiler.

Comment: @Pointy is your response valid when we have lot of methods and modules and that the whole uncompressed js file weight is more than 130KB and that it targets mobile platform?

Comment: Yes, it's valid.  Performance problems generally involve bad algorithms and/or excessive wasteful DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

The following function creates and returns an object, which contains the `main` method only:

```
var MyModule = function(callback){
    var count = 0;

    var secret = function(){
        if(count === 2){
            callback();
        } 
    }

    var main = function(){
        count ++;
        window.specialApi.doWorkAndCallback(secret);
    }

    main();

    return {
        main: main
    };
};
```

Then, the only thing you have to do, is to call this function once and store its returned value on a variable:

```
var module = MyModule(function(){console.log('ok');});
```

Finally, whenever you want to call `main` (and keep the old value of `count`), just do:

```
module.main();
```

Comment: Good try, but I don't need to keep the old value of count. Apart this, your code looks very close to mine (except you are using function expression vs function declaration for me)

Answer (score 0):

```
  //My lib
    var modul =  
        {
        count:0,
        callback:{},
        main: function(){
           this.count ++;                        
            window.specialApi.doWorkAndCallback(this.secret);     
        },
        secret: function(){
            if(this.count === 2){
              this.callback();
            } 
        }
    };


    modul.callback = function(){console.log("ok");};
    modul.main();

    modul.callback = function(){console.log("ok");};
    modul.main();

    modul.callback = function(){console.log("ok");};
    modul.main();

    modul.callback = function(){console.log("ok");};
    modul.main();
```

http://jsbin.com/emitoj/3/edit

Comment: This will break if you set the second modul.callback while the first window.specialApi.doWorkAndCallback has not finished yet. Because, when window.specialApi.doWorkAndCallback finishes, it will call the second callback and not the first one.